# Gradle adb Android Exec Task Hangs on Failure

Tags: android, shell, gradle, adb

I am trying to write a Gradle task that executes an adb command to clear the app/data cache for a connected android device:

```
task clearAppDataCache(type: Exec) {
    description = "Clears device app data/cache."
    group = "Utils"

    commandLine "$sdkDir/platform-tools/adb"
    args = ["shell", "pm", "clear", "com.my.package"]
}
```

The above task works if the com.my.package android package is installed on the device. However, if the package is not installed the task prints out a failure and then hangs in the following manner:

[image: Shell screen shot]

Does anyone know why this might be the case? I would expect it to instead failure and finish in a manner similar to how the raw shell command runs.

Edit:

The adding the following configuration clause to the task stops the hang:

```
doFirst {
        if (!packageExists("com.my.package"))
            throw new GradleException("com.my.package package is not installed on connected device.")
    }
```

with the following function definition:

```
/**
  * Returns true if the packageName argument exists on the the connected device,
  * false otherwise.
  */
def packageExists(String packageName) {
    def output = "adb shell pm list packages -f".execute().waitFor().text
    if (output.contains("$packageName")) return true
    return false
}
```

However, I am still searching for the reason why it hangs in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
task clearAppDataCache(type: Exec) {
    description = "Clears device app data/cache."
    group = "Utils"
    commandLine "./pmclear.sh"
}
```

pmclear.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "`adb shell "pm list packages com.my.package"`" == "" ] || adb shell "pm clear com.my.package
```

Comment: Still getting the same hang as described above.

Comment: I checked and `pm clear ...` does indeed get stuck. So make a simple script to check if the package is installed and call that from your gradle code instead.

Comment: Thanks Alex! That fixes this case, but I am still looking for the underlying cause of the problem.